# Use "belief" with or without the indefinite article?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Not counting set expressions, such as **contrary to popular belief** and **beyond belief**, I can't pinpoint the difference between **belief** and **a belief**.

And while Collin's learner's dictionary lists **belief** as uncountable, they offer two different examples:

> 1. One billion people throughout the world are Muslims, united by **belief**
>    in one god.
> 2. ...**a belief** in personal liberty.

Contrary to the first example, Google Books has more results for **united by a belief in one God** (Having only 6 search results as the sample size might be the problem though). :-)

I want to believe these examples are interchangeable, but that's too good to be true, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking this is just a special case of what *should* be addressed by [How do I know which article to use?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/197/), but I'm afraid no answer there seems to directly address the specific current case.

There's no context to have an opinion on example #2 above, but #1 could quite reasonably use ***the, a,*** or the "zero article". I'm inclined to think that ***the*** may (very slightly) elevate the status of ***belief***. If you want to be "literal", it implies the ***only*** [significant] belief (it's been "particularized", with the implication that *we all know which belief we're talking about*). So an Anglophone Muslim might (again, slightly) prefer that version.

Correspondingly therefore, one might suppose that using the indefinite article ***a*** slightly *downgrades* the status of the belief (since there's an implication that it's just one of many beliefs). So feasibly an *atheist* might prefer that version.

To round it off, I could say that using the zero article (as Collins did it their citation) steers a more neutral middle path. But to be honest, these three "distinctions" are becoming progressively more tenuous. It's far easier (and probably *accurate*) to just say they're equivalent/interchangeable.

---

The actual word ***belief*** isn't inherently countable or uncountable. Depending on context (surrounding syntax *and* intended meaning) it can be either.

Comment: Thanks! These smaller differences in meaning have finally made articles (a bit) easier for me.

Comment: @Atm5: Well, there was **a** good usage by *you!* It would *not* have been good if you'd said *finally made articles (**bit**) easier for me* :)

Comment: (and it wouldn't be **a** good to use that article here! :)

Comment: Not all is lost then! I will make sure to enjoy these teeny-tiny moments of correctness from now on.