# The use of article before the names of exercises

Tags: articles

Tell me please which article I have to use in the following sentence.

> Today I am going to train my chest by doing **the**/**a** bench press and **the*/**a** inclined dumbbell bench press.

I have definitely heard English native speakers trainers use both the definite and indefinite article, and even zero one. Is there a rule as to which articles one has to use before the names of exercises, or is it optional?

Comment: There is no specific rule for exercises, so your question is covered by [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a) and lots of others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Articles: When do I use "a", "the", or "\_\_"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/197/articles-when-do-i-use-a-the-or)

Comment: If there were such **a rule**, you could easily find it, right? ["train my chest" is a no-go.] Also, I believe we have answered this question before, so this tells me you might not have grasped the basic idea with the/a.

Answer (score 1):

**the bench press** refers to the lift  as prototype or archetype, not as an instance.  **a bench press** refers to a single instance of the class "bench press".

If I say

> Today, my plan is to do **a bench press**.

it means I will do just one of them.

If I say

> Today, my plan is to do **the bench press**.

it could mean, and probably does mean, that I am going to practice doing them, and will do several or even quite a few of them.  The only situation where it would refer to just one press is  where you'd discussed attempting this lift with someone, and now you're telling them that you plan to attempt it today, or some similar context. The meaning would be "the aforementioned bench-press".