# Which article is it correct to use before a noun that is modified by "called"?

Tags: articles

Do I have to use *a* or *the* in the following sentences?

> Kate is from **a**/**the** big city called New-York.
>
> The man is holding **a**/**the** thing called a table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Articles: When do I use "a", "the", or "\_\_"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/197/articles-when-do-i-use-a-the-or)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definite article (the) is used to indicate that the identity of the noun is known to the reader. The indefinite article (a) is used when its identity is not known.

So it all comes down to whether or not your audience has heard of "New York", or "a table" before.

I can't imagine anyone not knowing what a table is, but let's assume you're introducing a table to someone for the very first time.

> The man is holding a thing called a table.

There are lots of "things", not just one, so the indefinite article is correct.

I'll use the second example to explain why *knowing* the noun makes a difference.

If someone had never heard of New York, then it would be correct to say:

> Kate is from a big city called New-York.

This is because there are lots of big cities, not just one.

However, you could also say:

> Kate is from *the* city of New York.

Even though there are many cities, you are identifying that she comes from a *specific* city, and naming it, so the definite article *the* is appropriate.