'On the table' versus 'on a little table'
There is an example in the book that I use to learn English. There are two sentences:
The (book) is on the (table).
The (book) is on a little (table).

The author suggests that we should learn this pattern, but doesn't explain the reasoning behind it. For some reason I should use the indefinite article to tell about a specific thing if there is an adjective before it. Why is it so?
These are two additional examples from the textbook where this pattern is used:

Where are the flowers? - The flowers are in a beautiful vase.
Where is the vase? - The vase is on a little table near the window.


Please see this answer of mine that was downvoted by someone who doesn't know or understand this: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346533/does-an-apple-fall-from-a-tree-or-the-tree/346565#346565

I've read your answer. I guess that I understand it, but I'm still puzzled about the author's intention. Does he mean that the vase and the little table aren't known to another person?

Why does the author contrasts those two sentences that form the pattern that should be learnt?

How would you reason about it?

I disagree with the author. The choice of "the" depends on whether the then the noun references is known to the listener, either from context or from a previous mention. There's no reason why the listener couldn't be aware of a little table, so it's fine to say "The book is on the little table," if you know the listener is aware of that particular little table.

Are they claiming "on the table" is a generic position? If you say something is "on the floor" or "on the wall", you're not necessarily referring to a specific floor, you're just saying it's at ground level or stuck to some wall somewhere. I'm not sure if "on the table" works quite the same (except metaphorically: if an offer is on the table, it means it's available).

I don't really know what the author claims. He just presented the pattern and said to learn it. There wasn't any explanation. That's why I've posted the question. I needed some help to decipher the author's intent. The textbook that I use contains a lot of drill exercises. Those are very helpful to implant some patterns  and grammar constructions into your brain, but the explanations are too short to be helpful. I guess they are made with an idea that it's better to tell a half-truth than to explain every little detail from the get go.

You use the indefinite article to refer to a general thing, and the definite to refer to a specific thing. This is true no matter what adjectives are attached.
I'm not going to say your textbook is wrong, but the interpretation you've written in the question is definitely wrong.

The book is on the table.

There is only one table. Saying "the table" uniquely identifies it.

The book is on a table.

There are (potentially) many tables, and the book is on one of them.

The book is on the little table.

There is only one little table, and the book is on it. There may be other tables that are not little.

The book is on a little table.

There are (potentially) many little tables, and the book is on one of them. There may be other tables that are not little.
You can also use either the definite or indefinite article if the hearer of the sentence would be unfamiliar with the object in question. Both "The book is on a little table" and "The book is on the little table" are acceptable if the hearer knows nothing about the table, even if there is only one.

Note also that if you say "the book is on the table" and the hearer doesn't know anything about what tables there might be, then you are telling the hearer that there is only one table.

Got it, Peter. Thanks!

@MariosAthanasiou This person keeps saying this same thing to me as well. He upvotes an answer then asks for an upvote. I've told him this is not a good way to proceed...so now he's switched to you instead of me...

I can offer a practical scenario to help you decide which version to use.
You phone your sister, who will be coming to the party where you are now, to ask her to bring your phone, which you left at home accidentally.  You have borrowed a friend's phone to make the call.

Sis: Who is this?
You:  It's me.  I forgot my phone. I am using Mary's. Can you please bring it with you?
Sis:  Where is it?
You:  It is in my room on the table.

If there is only one table in your room, the above is good. She will know to look on the table in your room.
But what if it is in your dresser, which has two small half-height and half-width drawers on top, and full-height and full-width drawers below them. You cannot remember which little drawer you put your phone in:

You: It is in the dresser, in a little drawer.

She will know to look in the other little drawer if the  phone is not in the first little  drawer she opens.
That is just  one example. We would need  a thousand more examples to cover all of the remaining situations.

Thanks, Tim! It's impossible to mark several answers as accepted, but your answer contains a great example that is very helpful!

@snailontheslope Yes, in the dresser, there is only one. In a little drawer is non-specific. This follows the usage I mentioned in my answer.

Sample sentences:
The book is on the table. [a specific table]
The book is on a little table. [general, it could be any little table]
The book is on a table. [general]
The book is on the little table. [specific]
The adjective little can go with any of the four.
the table is the one the speakers know about, or that they have already established
a table is a general thing, not specific.
the table is specific to a specific context.

These exercises require to imagine the most probable situation. I guess, that I understand the idea of the author. The person, who asks the questions, probably knows about those vase and table, but there is a low probability  that those things were discussed recently. In such a case it would be inappropriate to say the vase meaning that vase. That's why 'a beautiful vase' is used. Do I reason correctly?

@snailontheslope Require imagining, no to. Think also of this: In English, you need either a plural, an a or a the. You can't have nothing in most cases of countable nouns. You can't do this: Book is on table. Do you see? "That's a beautiful vase, Look!" | That's the beautiful vase I was telling you about.

I understand that a noun should be in plural, or have a determiner, or there should be a good reason to use it alone. I guess, I was unable to convey my idea. I guess that those two people from the examples haven't been talking about the vase and the table recently. In such a situation there is no sense to use 'the beautiful vase' as they haven't been discussing it.

Do you remember the example? The vase is on a little table near the window.  It's clear that there is only one table near the window. So the 'any table'  explanation won't be applicable here.

@snailontheslope That's a general statement. compare: on the little table near the window. It follows the general/specific rule. On a little table near the window, the one with flowers on it.

Lambie, thanks for your attempts to help! I guess that I know the basics related to the articles. I'm aware about this specific/general thing. I just wanted to decipher a very special guideline from the textbook that I use. You can read my last comment to the question itself where I explain my idea better.

It's almost impossible to create many quality exercises related to the articles. As if you set the scene properly, then you will be able to fit only so many exercises into a textbook. The author builds a scene in his mind and asks about that scene. If you want to proceed doing the exercises, you need to use your imagination to fill the gaps by yourself. You need to try hard to read between the lines. I was unable to do it, so I asked for help.

@snailontheslope The answser will always be the same: a is general, the is specific. There is no other answer or rule. Even when you say: I went down to the school today to see my son's teacher.
